# Issue with inserting data comparing NULL Values

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue with inserting data comparing NULL Values.

I have a destination table fact_jpm_lea_temp and staging table debug_fact_jpm_lea_temp1

my query is

````
 insert into fact_jpm_lea_temp 
```
select
    SFS.employee_id,    
    SFS.shift_date,     
    SFS.sch_time_in, 
    SFS.sch_time_out,   
    now() as dwh_ins_ts ,
    now() as dwh_updt_ts
from
    debug_fact_jpm_lea_temp1 as SFS
where
    not exists (
    select
        *
    from
        fact_jpm_lea_temp DFS
    where
        DFS.employee_id = SFS.employee_id
        and DFS.shift_date = SFS.shift_date 
        and DFS.sch_time_in = SFS.sch_time_in
        and DFS.sch_time_out = SFS.sch_time_out
        and dfs.sch_time_in is null and dfs.sch_time_out is null
        
    )
```
````

I already have a record in my destination table as below where time in and time out are null and same in staging table as well I added extra condition dfs.sch_time_in is null and dfs.sch_time_out is null as well to eliminate but still not working.
188040  12/11/2023          2023-12-18 13:33:17.248 -0600   2023-12-18 13:33:17.248 -0600

and same value in staging table as well

When I try to insert it, its just keep on inserting even though it should not as both my staging and destination table data matches.

if employee id, shift_Date, time_in and time_out matches then it should not insert?

Comment: |employee_id|shift_date|sch_time_in|sch_time_out|dwh_ins_ts                   |dwh_updt_ts                  |
|-----------|----------|-----------|------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
|188,040    |12/11/2023|           |            |2023-12-18 13:33:17.248 -0600|2023-12-18 13:33:17.248 -0600|

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in the subquery will always be false because `dfs.sch_time_in = SFS.sch_time_in` and `dfs.sch_time_in IS NULL` are mutually exclusive. The same applies to `sch_time_out`. This can be addressed by changing the comparisons to `dfs.sch_time_in IS DISTINCT FROM sfs.sch_time_in AND dfs.sch_time_out IS DISTINCT FROM sfs.sch_time_out` and remove the ` NULL` checks. Keep in mind that doing so will not take advantage of  indexes on `sch_time_in` or `sch_time_out`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses [three valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).  There is `true`, `false` and `null`.  A `where` statement checks for truth, and `null` is not `true`.  So this `where` clause filters out all rows:

```
where   null = null
```

Surprisingly, any comparison with null also returns null.  So all of the following `where` clauses filter out all rows:

```
where   1 <> null
where   null < 1
where   1 in (1, 2, null)
```

A typical way to deal with that is to [`coalesce`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) the `null` values away:

```
coalesce(DFS.shift_date, '1970-01-01') = coalesce(SFS.shift_date, '1970-01-01')
```

Or to check for `null` using `is null`:

```
(DFS.shift_date = SFS.shift_date OR 
    (DFS.shift_date IS NULL AND SFS.shift_date IS NULL))
```

Or as @JohnH elegantly suggested in the comment, a Postgres specific solution is [`is distinct from`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):

```
DFS.shift_date is not distinct from SFS.shift_date
```

Comment: Thank you so much johnH and andomar. Appreciate your help. Thank you.